# Optimizing extracting values from a raster per polygon

Tags: r, parallel-processing, raster, terra

I have multiple raster layers (one for each hour; covering contiguous US) and a polygon vector layer. I am extracting the average value for each polygon from the raster layer using `terra::extract`. The process works fine for limited number of polygons and raster layers, but as I want to scale this up to multiple months with 1000+ polygons, I was wondering if there is a more optimized method to approach this.

The code snippet below shows a minimal reproducible example along with the desired output. I have thought of two possible routes to take, but have not made it so far implementing them:

1. I have thought about parallel processing but I am not sure how to achieve that without running into serialization issue here.
2. Instead of using `extract(..., fun = mean)` on every raster, I was thinking of doing something like `extract(mrast[[1]], mpoly, cells = TRUE, exact = TRUE)` and getting the cell numbers along with their exact coverage by each polygon. From there, I potentially can subset those cells (all of the raster layers have the same cells) for each hour, multiply their value by their exact fraction, and calculate the averages.
3. A combination of 2 and 1. I think this would be the fastest method.

```r
#setwd("C:/temp")
library(terra)
library(R.utils)

murl <- "https://mtarchive.geol.iastate.edu/2023/06/27/mrms/ncep/MultiSensor_QPE_01H_Pass2/"
mfiles <- c("MultiSensor_QPE_01H_Pass2_00.00_20230627-070000.grib2.gz", 
           "MultiSensor_QPE_01H_Pass2_00.00_20230627-080000.grib2.gz")

## download, unzip, read the raster files to R
lapply(seq_along(mfiles), \(i) download.file(paste0(murl, mfiles[i]), mfiles[i])) 
lapply(mfiles, \(f) gunzip(f, gsub(".gz", "", f), remove = TRUE, overwrite=TRUE))

mrast <- lapply(list.files(pattern = ".grib2$"), \(f) rast(f)) 
lapply(seq_along(mrast), \(i) names(mrast[[i]]) <<- time(mrast[[i]]))

## creating a polygon shapefile
mpoly <- vect(dptply, "polygon") ## get dptply at the bottom of the post
crs(mpoly) <- "EPSG:3857"
mpoly <- project(mpoly, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

## extracting the averages (this part needs optimization)
startTime = Sys.time()
mavg <- lapply(mrast, \(r) {op <- extract(r, mpoly, 
                                         weights=TRUE, fun=mean, na.rm = TRUE)
                            message(time(r))
                            return(op)})
endTime = Sys.time()
print(endTime - startTime)

2023-06-27 07:00:00
2023-06-27 08:00:00
Time difference of 10.87896 secs
```

```
## just for demonstration
cbind(mavg[[1]][1], do.call(cbind, lapply(mavg, "[", 2)))
#>    ID 2023-06-27 07:00:00 2023-06-27 08:00:00
#> 1   1            0.000000           10.405161
#> 2   2            0.000000            8.961424
#> 3   3            0.000000            6.300000
#> 4   4            0.000000            5.902914
#> 5   5            0.000000            5.462630
#> 6   6            0.000000            4.100000
#> 7   7            0.000000            3.566511
#> 8   8            0.000000           13.275161
#> 9   9            2.600000           11.200000
#> 10 10            4.633752           16.301403
```

##### Data:

```r
dptply <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                      4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 
                      8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -7945530.9815, -7938378.0621, -7938605.1389, 
                      -7945190.3663, -7945530.9815, -7938264.5237, -7936674.9861, -7930543.9123, 
                      -7932360.5267, -7936674.9861, -7938264.5237, -7938264.5237, -7934698.4679, 
                      -7933886.647, -7933878.7652, -7934666.9409, -7934698.4679, -7933735.8469, 
                      -7932622.0601, -7932634.9736, -7933745.532, -7933735.8469, -7934646.4483, 
                      -7933925.1099, -7933904.9326, -7934631.3153, -7934646.4483, -7933551.8299, 
                      -7932850.6689, -7932865.8018, -7933496.3424, -7933551.8299, -7931645.765, 
                      -7931670.3955, -7932384.6797, -7932470.8864, -7931645.765, -7940928.6868, 
                      -7941271.2217, -7941328.3108, -7948978.2562, -7949434.9693, -7940928.6868, 
                      -7998760.8958, -7999220.4225, -7998966.0077, -7998636.765, -7998760.8958, 
                      -8001395.2248, -8001358.6877, -8003002.8551, -8003149.0033, -8001395.2248, 
                      5262480.6428, 5262635.0714, 5251676.934, 5251831.1854, 5262480.6428, 
                      5262789.5025, 5268041.6687, 5261862.9539, 5252293.955, 5248438.2361, 
                      5248900.8391, 5262789.5025, 5269309.6397, 5269309.6397, 5269052.1707, 
                      5269041.443, 5269309.6397, 5269446.29, 5269441.8957, 5267934.7856, 
                      5267925.9984, 5269446.29, 5271218.9923, 5271198.3903, 5270580.3524, 
                      5270607.8199, 5271218.9923, 5272036.2399, 5272049.9757, 5271507.4245, 
                      5271239.5943, 5272036.2399, 5272266.345, 5270589.7139, 5270556.1843, 
                      5272216.0417, 5272266.345, 5246883.428, 5237972.8, 5237895.3531, 
                      5238282.5936, 5247503.6111, 5246883.428, 5227512.1703, 5227597.3282, 
                      5228266.5923, 5228286.8738, 5227512.1703, 5232252.738, 5229875.3018, 
                      5229528.6423, 5232104.1307, 5232252.738, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                      0, 0, 0, 0), 
                    dim = c(53L, 5L), 
                    dimnames = list(NULL, c("geom", "part", "x", "y", "hole")))
```

Comment: Have you tried using {exactextractr} instead of {terra}? Should be faster.

Comment: @nukubiho not here, but have tested that before, and it was considerably slower for other raster calcs that I needed then.

Comment: Another potential approach is to use `mask` before `extract`, e.g. `mrast <- lapply(mrast, \(r) mask(r, mpoly))`.  This can also be run before Robert Hacken's approach for a slightly faster solution, at which point almost all of the advantages of parallel computing come from running the masking in parallel (as the remaining extract operation is very quick on masked data).

Comment: @CPB I am sure (have tested it) that the overhead time that masking/clipping adds to the process is more than what it saves.

Comment: On my machine the original question code runs in 11.04 secs and the masked code runs in 2.75 secs (adding `mrast <- lapply(mrast, \(r) mask(r, mpoly))` just after `startTime = Sys.time()` so the masking is included in the time taken).

Comment: @CPB oh, no, I meant compared to reading the cells from the full raster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much answered yourself, here is how I would approach this using option 2.

First let's find which cells (`cell` column) are in which polygons (`ID`) and what fraction of them (`fraction`). This takes time but will only be performed once.

```r
cells <- terra::extract(mrast[[1]], mpoly, cells=TRUE, exact=TRUE)
head(cells)
#   ID 2023-06-27 08:00:00    cell  fraction
# 1  1                 9.8 8629863 0.2353906
# 2  1                 9.6 8629864 0.4162643
# 3  1                 9.8 8629865 0.4321375
# 4  1                10.2 8629866 0.4480107
# 5  1                10.3 8629867 0.4638838
# 6  1                10.1 8629868 0.4797569
```

Using this information, we can extract data for polygons without dealing with their geometry, just using the cell numbers from above. Here is a function which takes a raster (`rast`) and the data above `cell_data` as its arguments and computes weighted (let's be exact!) means for each polygon:

```r
polygon_means <- function(rast, cell_data) {
  # values for cells
  ex <- terra::extract(rast, cell_data$cell)
  # weighted means by polygons
  tapply(ex[, 1] * cell_data$fraction, cell_data$ID, sum) / 
    tapply(cell_data$fraction, cell_data$ID, sum)
}
```

Now we can do the computation:

```r
names(mrast) <- sapply(mrast, names)
mavg <- sapply(mrast, polygon_means, cells)
mavg
#    2023-06-27 07:00:00 2023-06-27 08:00:00
# 1             0.000000           10.405166
# 2             0.000000            8.959888
# 3             0.000000            6.300000
# 4             0.000000            5.902433
# 5             0.000000            5.462595
# 6             0.000000            4.100000
# 7             0.000000            3.566484
# 8             0.000000           13.275182
# 9             2.600000           11.200000
# 10            4.633801           16.301409
```

This takes about 3 seconds on my machine, which is about 10 times faster than your original code (yes, 30 seconds on my laptop).

Thinking about your option 1, i.e. parallelizing, its usefulness would probably depend on your computing environment. Since the `SpatRaster` data is not actually in RAM and has to be read from the disk each time it is accessed, on a one-disk machine this might be the main bottleneck which distributing the computation among multiple processor cores would not help solve.

###### Extracting by cell numbers vs. row and column indices

I don't think there will be much practical difference in how you access the raster values. Under the hood, both `extract` and `[` call some variant of a C++ extracting function (e.g., `.extract_cell()`). Compare

```r
selectMethod(terra::extract, c('SpatRaster', 'numeric'))
selectMethod('[', c('SpatRaster', 'numeric', 'numeric'))
```

Comment: Thank you. As you mentioned, to avoid serialization issues with parallal processing, we'd have to read the SpatVector each time (pass the filename to the loop), however I don't think reading the SpatRaster would be the bottleneck (we'd load each raster once). The only thing that I am still wondering about is whether finding the x and y (row and column) instead of cell number and using `[` to subset (e.g. `mraster [rows, cols, 1]`) would be even faster than using `extract` with the cell number.

Comment: @M-- This shouldn't matter much, se my edit.

Comment: That makes sense. If anything, it seems that `[` would be slower. On another note, I think to even make this process faster, we could use parallel processing for `polygon_means` function. That is actually gonna help since we only read the `SpatVector` once, and every `SpatRaster` is also loaded only once.

Comment: I noticed that this solution gives slightly different results, e.g. the last line here is 4.633801, 16.301409 compared to the original 4.633752, 16.301403.

Comment: @CPB Yes, that's because it computes a *weighted* mean.

Answer (score -1):

The standard way to do this would be to extract the values for all rasters in one step

```
library(terra)
rr <- rast(list.files(pattern = ".grib2$")) 
mavg <- extract(rr, mpoly, weights=TRUE, fun=mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This essentially does the same thing as what you are trying to achieve with your loop. It should be faster, but certainly is easier.

Comment: Is it any faster than the loop?

Comment: @M-- Not really.